# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSAlert' Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

Can't I use NSAlert in a SKScene ?

```
 let alert = NSAlert()
 alert.addButtonWithTitle("Close")
 alert.messageText = "Game over"
 alert.informativeText = "You won!"
 alert.runModal()
```

> ERROR : unresolved identifier 'NSAlert' Swift 4

Comment: What happens if you do so?

Comment: NSAlert is the Mac OS one, maybe you're on iOS?

Comment: But How to switch to MacOS ?

Comment: @NicoHaase It gives this compiler error "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSAlert'

Comment: @Moritz cannot import cocoa it says there is no package like that

Comment: `NSAlert` is a class for macOS found in the AppKit framework. Are you working on an iOS or macOS app?

Comment: @rmaddy iOS so how can I use an alert in iOS

Comment: `UIAlertController`.

Comment: but @rmaddy It is not working for me, can you answer a example coding for UIAlertController

Answer (score 1):

`NSAlert` is an OS X API. Since you are on iOS, use `UIAlertController`:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in print("You clicked OK") }
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in print("You clicked Cancel") }

alert.addAction(okAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you are inside an `SKView`, try this:

```
if let vc = self.window?.rootViewController {
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: value of type 'SKView' has no member 'present'
I get this error then